# How to check if given object is an empty / null enumerable?

Tags: c#

I have a requirement where I get an object (`System.Object`) and I need to check if the object is null or empty. This object could be a value type / derived from `IEnumerable<T>`

Basically, I want a function like this:

```
public void Validator(object val)
{
    // returns true, if non-empty and non-null
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't your method accept an `IEnumerable<T>` then?

Comment: Since it can also be a value type, do you want to return `false` if `val` contains the default value for the value type? For instance, if `val` is `int` and `0`.

Comment: Fix your function signature, as it is returning void instead of bool.

Comment: Be careful: it isn't possible to check an arbitrary enumerable is empty without, you know, enumerating it. This invalidates enumerables that can only be enumerated once (like results coming from a database). If a method has a need for processing an enumerable it cannot check for emptiness up front separately (but it can throw an error on finding the enumerable is empty). A super-general method like this validating arbitrary `object`s is almost certainly a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use the `switch` expression with the type pattern:

```
public bool Validator(object val) => val switch 
{
    null => false,
    IEnumerable e => e.GetType().IsGenericType && e.GetEnumerator().MoveNext(),
    _ => true
};
```

This works only for generic enumerables.
Simply omit the `e.GetType().IsGenericType &&` if you want it to work for non-generic enumerables as well:

```
public bool Validator(object val) => val switch 
{
    null => false,
    IEnumerable e => e.GetEnumerator().MoveNext(),
    _ => true
};
```

Comment: If I recall correctyy, there is no `Any` linq extension methd defined for non-generic `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @mjwills I did now and I've rectified it to work , thanks :)

Comment: I get inconsistent results with this function: `Validator(0) == true`, `Validator(new[] { 1 }) == false`, `Validator(new ArrayList() { 1, 2 }) == false`. Also, missing semicolon at the end.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues You'll have to omit the `e.GetType().IsGenericType &&` for it to work for non-generic enumerables as mentioned.

Comment: Why the catch-all case returns true? It should return false if object is not enumerable at all, no? like Validator(0)

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues The question describes that `val` can be a value type if not an enumerable for which `true` has to be returned

Answer (score 2):

Correct your method signature to return `bool` instead of `void`:

```
public static bool Validator(object val) {
    return val is IEnumerable e && e.Cast<object>().Any();
}

// some tests
var isNull       = Validator(null);                     // false
var isScalar     = Validator(0);                        // false
var isArray      = Validator(new[] { 1 });              // true
var isEmpty      = Validator(new object[] {});          // false
var isNonGeneric = Validator(new ArrayList() { 1, 2 }); // true
var isGeneric    = Validator(new List<int> { 1, 2 });   // true
```

Comment: Would need to check for the generic variant of the interface instead/as well, there's no guarantee an object would implement the generic variant if it implemented the non-generic one.

Comment: Done, it now works for both generic and non-generic enumerables

Comment: I'd forgotten `IEnumerable<T>` derives from `IEnumerable` :)